# What changed to OpenLayers that affected my code?

Tags: openlayers

I created a map application to display IGC files and track waypoints. It was fully functional and then it stopped working.

I created a web application using OpenLayers to display waypoints and IGC files for pilots.

It was a fully functional site and then it stopped working unexpectedly. What could have gone wrong with OpenLayers? I have the site hosted in GitHub pages but I get the same issue on my local copy.

In the browser console I get the following error: 
Loading failed for the  with source “http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/build/ol.js”.

Examples:
Waypoints page: [https://f0n.github.io/xcbohl/waypoints/]

IGC page: [https://f0n.github.io/xcbohl/scfr3/]

Comment: OpenLayers has removed most old versions from its site.  It is best to take your own copy of the library, however it is also available on some CDNs for example https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers/3.10.1

Comment: Thanks. Having my own copy of the library gave me some trouble with GH Pages. Thus, I used their repository. But I will sure use the CDNs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source for version 3.10.1 of OpenLayers is no longer there. I changed it to version 5.3.0 and it worked.